# pyautogui.click is not clicking after calling subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to automate launching of a program on Windows. I've tried giving the path to `subprocess.Popen`, however I get the UAC pop up, so to work around I created a task on task scheduler and targeted the shortcut.

The problem I'm facing is that once I run the below script, the program opens nicely, pyautogui is able to move the mouse to the buttons on the UI but the click does not seem to be registering.

I've also tried `openGI.terminiate()` to close the subprocess and return control to the script but what happens is that the script ends after opening the program and the atutomation does not happen.

```
import subprocess
import pyautogui
import time

openGI = subprocess.Popen('C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /TN \GI')
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.click((1671, 832))
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.click((1661, 961)) #click launch
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.click((1236, 829)) #click start
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.click((1287, 829)) #click to begin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pyautogui.doubleClick()` instead of `pyautogui.click()` where you need to launch the program

Comment: Hi dk_28, I've tried pyautogui.doubleClick() as well but the click does not register. I only see the mouse moving to the spot but there was no click being triggered.

Comment: Then, I'm not sure as only used pyautogui once for my side project. But I can suggest you [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). It will help you automate tasks on your windows machine and there are plenty of tutorials for the same as well.